# I am not able to use lazy-loading in angular 15 with asp.net application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am using Angular application with asp.net. and at the time of build the project showing followings erros.

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Here is my ts-configuration setting.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "../Bundles/AngularOutput",
    "noImplicitOverride": false,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": false,
    "strictTemplates": false
  }
}
```

in above configuration if I change module flag from ES2022 to commonJs then it works fine, but by doing this lazyloading not works properly.

Please suggest any solution for this